# Analytical relationship between prior and posterior distributions by Markov Chain Monte Carlo?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, posterior

I am trying to conceptualize the analytical relationship between the prior distribution and posterior distribution obtained by MCMC for Bayesian inference. Sorry for the non-rigorous notation but I hope it still communicates the idea.

This [thesis by Zhou](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~georgy/research/texture/thesis-html/node37.html) suggests that the 
posterior $\Pr(X^n) = \Pr(X^n | \textit{data})$ of parameter $X$ can be obtained through $n$ acceptance steps via the prior $\Pr(X^0)$ and product of transition probabilities $\Pr(X^t | X^{t-1}) = \Pr(X^t | X^{t-1}, \textit{data})$:
\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X^n) = \Pr(X^0) \prod_{t=1}^n \Pr(X^t | X^{t-1})
\end{equation}
($\textit{data}$ is omitted to simplify notation.)

[Asher et al.](https://www.elsevier.com/books/parameter-estimation-and-inverse-problems/aster/978-0-12-385048-5) writes that the limiting distribution that approximates the posterior distribution is obtained by:
\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X^n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Pr(X^n | X^0)
\end{equation}

According to the [Chapman-Kolmogorov equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chapman-KolmogorovEquation.html), 
\begin{align}
  \Pr(X^n | X^0) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Pr(X^n | x) \Pr(x | X^0) dx
\end{align}

My question is: I am not sure this relationship equivalent?
\begin{align}
\Pr(X^n | X^0) \stackrel{?}{=} \Pr(X^0) \prod_{t=1}^n \Pr(X^t | X^{t-1})
\end{align}

Is there another way to conceptualize the relationship between $\Pr(X^0)$ and $\Pr(X^n)$ through transition probabilities?

Comment: This is most confusing as you only mention a sequence $(X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and no parameter or observation. In which sense is this Bayesian or related with MCMC?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I've now stated that $X$ is in fact the parameter and the observation or data is implied but not included to simplify the notation.

Comment: Still confused by the fact that the parameter is of increasing size. What is the meaning of $n$?

Comment: $n$ is the index of iteration - while it looks like an exponent I have seen this notation to describe steps in MCMC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation 
\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X^n) = \Pr(X^0) \prod_{t=1}^n \Pr(X^t | X^{t-1})
\end{equation}
is incorrect, it should be
\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X^n) = \int \Pr(x^0) \prod_{t=1}^{n-1} \Pr(x^t | x^{t-1})\Pr(X^n | x^{n-1}) \,\text{d}x^0\cdots\,\text{d}x^{n-1}
\end{equation}or
\begin{equation}
  \Pr(X^n|X^0) = \int \prod_{t=1}^{n-1} \Pr(x^t | x^{t-1})\Pr(X^n | x^{n-1}) \,\text{d}x^1\cdots\,\text{d}x^{n-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: This clears it up! Thanks - so basically you have to integrate between all states x$^1$ to x$^{n-1}$. So is it correct that the product should go from $t=1$ to $t=n-1$ rather than $t=1$ to $t=n$?

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected!